# Grouping of tags - possible or not?

Tags: discussion, ignored-tags

The problem that I repeatedly encounter is the following: I have set up a list of tags that are to be ignored, because I don't know anything about the subject. However, to various general tags (like `angular`, `jquery` or the likes) there are also more specific tags available that could be provided by users.
However, if I wanted to ignore these, I would also have to add them to the list which could easily add up extraneous tags.

Now, would it be possible to associate these tags in a tree-like fashion so that general tags on a particular subject also includes the more specific ones? That would greatly help unclutter both the watch and ignore lists and would help suppress any questions that can be attributed to said broader subject (as an example, a question tagged with `angular-6` could indirectly be assigned to the `angular`tag as well), and when you are either watching or ignoring `angular`, that would automatically affect the more specific tags.

Would that be a viable option to be added to this site?
Right now the situation is unsatisfactory insofar that even when one decides to watch or ignore a particular general topic, there are still questions on this subject that show up on the list just because alternate tags have been used.

Comment: This is one of those strongly supported requests which, over the past 4 years, have been repeatedly declined. Don't expect anything better than dismissal. [SO no longer reads requests from core users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348?noredirect=1#comment1030131_314348).